# How do I access data in the view from my controller? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have data I'm getting in my controller and want to display it in the view. I've tried using a helper method but no luck. I've also tried an instance variable but still doesn't work.

Comment: Please post your `code` that you have tried.

Comment: You should share an example of code which didn't work so that someone can take it forward from there.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so like this :

```
class SomeClass < ApplicationController
  def index
    @something = 'This is a cool text'
  end
end
```

In the `index.html.erb` you can do this :

```
<%= @something %>
```